# How to merge these 2 dataframes with pandas efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I need to merge the label dataframe to the feature dataframe like this:

**Label Dataframe:**

| Time (integer) | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| ... | ... |

**Feature Dataframe:**

| Time (float) | Feature1 | Feature2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ... | ... |
| 0.5 | ... | ... |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 1.5 | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

**the result dataframe should be something like this:**

| Time (float) | Feature1 | Feature2 | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ... | ... | a |
| 0.5 | ... | ... | a |
| 1 | ... | .. | b |
| 1.5 | ... | ... | b |
| 2 | ... | ... | c |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

which means, for example in **0~1s**, the **label** is **a**; in **1~2s**,the **label** is **b**; etc.

I have 100,000+ rows in the actural dataframe. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: The first dataframe is not shown correctly in the question

Comment: have a look at [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) and play with the options.

Comment: Yes! It seems to be the exact function I'm looking for. Thanks! @QuangHoang

Answer (score 0):

One option is

```
df2['Label'] = df2['Time'].astype(int).map(df1.set_index('Time').squeeze())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:    `df1.merge(df2)`

[The official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge)

Comment: Actually, the function `pd.merge_asof` works well.